# Power Pivot error when getting data from ACCESS query

Tags: excel, powerpivot

The data I was using in EXCEL pivot tables suddenly went beyond the row limit for EXCEL;  Went to 1.7 million rows.  Now I need to use power Pivot but have the following issue.  I have a query (view) in ACCESS that adds a lot of derived fields to transaction data for year, month, day, etc, so the user doesn't have to add those. It's a straight up Select query. I go into Power pivot and chose databases then ACCESS, set the path to the ACCESS database, and the test is successful. When I go to the tables or views I see the query in the list.But after selecting it, when I hit next to load the data I get the following error:

"OLE DB or ODBC error: ODBC--connection to 'LDODBC' failed.; 3151.

An error occurred while processing table '1ACTMasterQuery'.

The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed."

I am using linked tables in the ACCESS app using an ODBC pipe named LDODBC, and none of those show in the list of tables or views. Do I need to set a connection string? There is no good explanation I could find on the web. What part don't I understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend NOT to connect to a query. Save the query result into an Access table first. Then connect to the saved table from PowerBI - it will be simple, fast and robust.

Comment: Figured that out yesterday.  Thanks for the answer.  It's all you said.